# Can't add record when using TinyMCE

Tags: database, tinymce, records

I would like to add a record to my database. Before I used a simple textarea to do this. But I wanted something more, so I decided to implement tinyMCE.

Everything works if you're just typing in some lines in the tinyMCE textarea. But if you are copy pasting something in it and then want to add it to the database, it won't work. You'll get the following message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; margin: 0px; out' at line 2

I think it had something to do with the '' things and the comma's. How can I solve this?

This is my query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO items (itemTitle,itemContent,itemDate,pageID,catName,itemFlag)
    VALUES ('$title','$content','$date','$pageID','$catName','$itemFlag')")or die(mysql_error());
```

where content is the content that I copy paste into the tinyMCE textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to escape quotes when inserting your editor content into your database.

You are using the function mysql_query, so i guess your script language is php.
Here is the code to escape quotes.

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
```